# node.js async; counting callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, callback, get

How does counting instances of a callback function work in node.js?

I was working on the 9th exercise of learnyounode (below the official solution).
As I understand it, the httpGet function is called three times, running through process.argv[2], [3] and [4]. But how could count ever === 3? Don't the individual functions just get to one? How does one call of httpGet know of the other ones?

```js
var http = require('http')
var bl = require('bl')
var results = []
var count = 0

function printResults () {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    console.log(results[i])
}

function httpGet (index) {
  http.get(process.argv[2 + index], function (response) {
    response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
      if (err)
        return console.error(err)

      results[index] = data.toString()
      count++

      if (count == 3)
        printResults()
    }))
  })
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  httpGet(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how could count ever === 3?

`count` is defined outside of `httpGet` and thus its value is independent of the those function calls. `count++` is the same as `count = count + 1`, i.e. every call to `httpGet` increases the value of `count` by `1`. The third time the function is called, `count`'s value will be `3`.

We can easily replicate this:

```js
var count = 0;

function httpGet() {
  count++;
  console.log('count: ', count);
  if (count === 3) {
    console.log('count is 3');
  }
}

httpGet();
httpGet();
httpGet();
```

Comment: Thanks once again, Felix! So, if the value of count increases between calling the function getHttp and it having executed to the point of count++, it will +1 already on the increased value? I thought it might just increase the value of count, as it was when the function was called.

Comment: The value of `count` is not read until the expression `count++` is executed. And because JavaScript is single threaded and has the concept of "run to completion" it is guaranteed that no two functions can execute that line at the same time or that one function updates the value between another function reading the value and updating it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that cleared a fundamental misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 1):

First, prefer not using `var`.

`var` is defined in the global scope so it’s value updated between calls

Read more about `var` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var?retiredLocale=he)